# Javascript Cross browsing issue on firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am facing an issue may be I am doing mistake. The issue is that I have to show a tooltip on hover in asp.net using vb.net and javascript. However it is working fine on all browsers but not on firefox. So far I searched a lot and up till now I think that the issue is of window.event which firefox does not supports but I used in my code. Is there any alternative according to my code so please let me know. Currently the logic which I used is that the POCESS_ONE, PROCESS_TWO, PROCESS_THREE, PROCESS_FOUR values are coming from database accordingly but actually these values will be shown on tooltip at mouse hover event. My java script code is below.

```
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Status">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessOne" CssClass="progressImg one" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveFirst.png" onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()"  />
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessTwo" CssClass="progressImg two" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveMid.png"  onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessThree" CssClass="progressImg three" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveMid.png"  onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProcessFour" CssClass="progressImg four" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/inActiveLast.png"  onmouseover="getData(this);" onmouseout="hideData()" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_ONE" HeaderText="" >
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_TWO" HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_THREE" HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROCESS_FOUR" HeaderText="">
                                <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                <HeaderStyle  CssClass="hiddencol"/>
                            </asp:BoundField>


    function hideData() {
                $DS('.toolTip').hide();
            }
            function getData(arg) {

                //var event = document.createEvent('Event');

                var process = arg.id;
                var Value;


                document.onmouseover = function (event) {


                    var evtSource;
                    if (document.all) {
                        evtSource = event.srcElement;
                    }
                    else {
                        evtSource = event.target;
                    }
                    //var event = event || window.event;
                    event = event || window.event;

                }
                //var clientX = event.clientX;
                //var clientY = event.clientY;
                var str;
                var showTip = true;
                if (process.indexOf('imgProcessOne') > 1) {
                    Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.textContent;
                    if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
                }
                if (process.indexOf('imgProcessTwo') > 1) {
                    Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
                    if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
                }
                if (process.indexOf('imgProcessThree') > 1) {
                    Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
                    if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
                }
                if (process.indexOf('imgProcessFour') > 1) {
                    Value = arg.parentElement.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
                    if (Value == "N") { showTip = false; }
                }

                if (showTip == true) {
                    str = "<table class='paymentTrackerTooltip' style='background-image: url(../../../images/tooltip2.png);'><tr><td>" + Value + "</td></tr></table>";
                    $DS('.toolTip .content').html(str).css('background', 'transparent').css('border', 'none');
                    $DS('.toolTip').css('left', event.clientX - 40).css('top', event.clientY - 70).css('display', 'block');
                    // $DS('.toolTip').css('display', 'block');

                    //$DS('.toolTip .bg').css('height', Auto).css();
                }
                else { return false; }

            }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing all your `.nextSibling` to `.nextElementSibling`

`nextElementSibling` always returns an element (tag). `nextSibling` can return any kind of node (like the text node that contains the newline etc that doesn't effect rendering, well, not always)

Comment: thank you so much @Jaromanda X  for your reply. I appreciate your interest. But it did not worked. Any other suggestion would you like to suggest me? Anyone can suggest me? thanks

Comment: you can respond 100 times in 10 minutes, `it did not worked` tells me no extra information I can possibly use to help you with